# Как обращаться из cgi-bin директории в www?

Tags: perl

У кого есть localhost в виде Denwer знают, что там структура папок примерно такая:

```
localhost
  www
  cgi-bin
```

Я еще совсем недавно начал работать с Perl. И возникла такая проблема.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use HTML::Template;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
$template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'skin/index.tmpl');
```

Этот скрипт работал безотказно, когда в .htaccess было Options +ExecCGI и файл .pl был вместе с остальными, в директории www. Но я решил, что лучше ему будет там, где положено - в cgi-bin. Но почему-то после перевода его туда функция print перестала работать в любом месте после объявления переменной template.
Я думаю, что это из-за пути к index.tmpl, так как оттуда наверняка он должен быть другой. Но не знаю, как его написать. ../skin/index.tmpl и ../www/skin/index.tmpl не работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В использовании cgi-bin нет никакого особо смысла, особенно под денвером, так что лучше вернуть файл в www и не придумывать проблемы.

Вообще путь "../www/skin/index.tmpl" по идее должен работать.

Попробуйте так:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use HTML::Template;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $template;
eval {
    $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => '../www/skin/index.tmpl');
};
if($@){
  print "Error: $@\n";
} else {
  print "All is OK\n";
}
```

Comment: Думаю, что проще папку с шаблонами тоже положить в папку cgi-bin и все заработает...